# Annoying Redirect Warning: How to Bypass or Disable It

Tags: redirect

i face annoying redirect notice on my webite   [bluearc best desiner company](https://stackoverflow.com)

How can I avoid or turn off the irritating redirect warning messages what should i do for this can to give sugesstion how to i use that i couuld'nt face google redirection notice again

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.